Is it possible to show this Integral identity, by assuming the hyposeses I have made?
Assume there exists $p>2$ such that $B\in L^p_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Assume in addition that there exists  $\tau >2$ such that
\begin{equation} \label{B-decay-cond}
|B(x)| \, = \, O(|x|^{-\tau}) \qquad as  \quad|x| \to \infty.
\end{equation}
We now define
\begin{equation} \label{h-eq}
h(x) =- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy,
\end{equation}
so that the vector field given by
\begin{equation} \label{A-h-def} 
A_h = (\partial_{x_2} h, - \partial_{x_1} h)
\end{equation}
satisfies $\nabla\times  A_h = B$. Thanks to Assumption above we have
\begin{equation} \label{A-L-infty}
|A_h| \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2).
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\alpha= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{\mathbb{R}^2}B\, dx 
\end{equation}
Notice that
\begin{equation} \label{exp-h-asymp}
e^{h(x)} = |x|^{-\alpha}\big(1+ O(|x|^{-1})\big) , \qquad as \quad |x|\to \infty.  
\end{equation}
I'm struggling to show the above identity, for convenience I'll call it Integral Identity (II). I thought I could proceed in this way:
$$
\exp\left\{- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy\right\}
$$
where
$$
- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy=- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{K} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy- \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy
$$
Let's call
$$
I_1=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{K} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy; \quad I_2=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy
$$
Either $I_1$, or $I_2$ are convergent because of the assumption. Then because of the second part of the assumption one gets
$$
I_2=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy, \quad \text{where}\quad 
   B(y)\log|x-y|)=O(|y|^{-\tau})\log|x-y| \quad \text{as} \quad |x|\to\infty
$$
Then, I'm stuck...

Eventually I reckon this is a possible answer:
To show the asymptotic behavior of $ e^{h(x)} $ as $ |x| \to \infty $, we need to analyze the integral expression for $ h(x) $ given by
$$ h(x) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log |x-y|\, dy. $$
Step-by-Step Solution:

Asymptotic Expansion of $ \log |x-y| $:
For large $ |x| $, we can use the expansion:
$$ \log |x-y| = \log |x| + \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right|. $$
Since $ \Big| \dfrac{y}{x} \Big| $ is small for large $ |x| $, we can approximate:
$$ \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right| \approx - \frac{y \cdot x}{|x|^2}. $$

Substitute the Expansion into $ h(x) $:
$$
   h(x) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \left( \log |x| + \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right| \right) dy.
   $$
This separates into two integrals:
$$
   h(x) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \log |x| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \, dy - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right| dy.
   $$

Evaluate the First Integral:
By definition, the first integral is:
$$
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \, dy = 2\pi \alpha.
   $$
Therefore,
$$
   - \frac{1}{2\pi} \log |x| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \, dy = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \log |x| \cdot 2\pi \alpha = - \alpha \log |x|.
   $$

Evaluate the Second Integral:
For the second integral, note that $ \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right| $ is small for large $ |x| $. Hence, the integral:
$$
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} B(y) \log \left| 1 - \frac{y}{x} \right| dy
   $$
will be of order $ O(|x|^{-1}) $ due to the decay condition $ |B(y)| = O(|y|^{-\tau}) $ with $ \tau > 2 $.

Combine the Results:
Combining the results from the two integrals, we get:
$$
   h(x) = - \alpha \log |x| + O(|x|^{-1}).
   $$

Exponentiate $ h(x) $:
Now, exponentiate $ h(x) $:
$$
   e^{h(x)} = e^{-\alpha \log |x| + O(|x|^{-1})}.
   $$
This can be written as:
$$
   e^{h(x)} = e^{-\alpha \log |x|} \cdot e^{O(|x|^{-1})}.
   $$
Since $ e^{-\alpha \log |x|} = |x|^{-\alpha} $, we have:
$$
   e^{h(x)} = |x|^{-\alpha} \cdot \left( 1 + O(|x|^{-1}) \right).
   $$


